# Open a File in with shell script in application without new instance?

Tags: bash, drag-and-drop, pid

I've got a picture converting tool for ubuntu which opens a window, where you can drag-and-drop a jpeg and automatically convert it in to a .wepb file.

This tool was written for the company that I work for and is automatically converting the pictures in to webp and adds a watermark logo on each picture so I have to use this tool. As far as I know, it's an xwindow tool using XDND for drag and drop. The person who wrote it is not reachable anymore.

Another option is to convert the pictures directly via the command line:

```
user@linux-desktop: ./jpeg2webp /Home/User/Dekstop/Pic1.jpeg
```

It work fine but when i use the bash/shell script it always opens a new instance of the Application.

Is there a way to tell the script to open the jpeg in the already opened instance maybe via the pid and prevent opening another instance? Or emulate a drag-and-drop on the app-window with the file path?

for example:

```
tell /Home/User/Dekstop/Pic1.jpeg to drag and drop on ./jpeg2webp application window
```

Comment: The question makes sense, but you are asking it at the wrong place.  Your question is not really about programming, but on how to control `jpeg2web`, so perhaps [su] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: _"Is there a way to tell the script to open the jpeg in the already opened instance"_ Not that I know of. Each program is responsible of its behavior in this case. For example if you type `google-chrome` in two separate terminals then it won't open two instances of google-chrome; the shell doesn't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find any information about the application you are using.

An alternative approach would be to use [imagemagicks](https://imagemagick.org/) `convert` tool:

```
convert in.jpg out.webp
```

For convenience you could also use a small wrapper script to convert a file while keeping the original filename:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="${1%.*}"  #get name from command line argument
convert "$1" "$name".webp
```

And run it as following:

```
./cwepb foo.jpg
```